# html5 Geolocation API with Geofencing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I'm working on a project using HTML5 Geolocation API and currently using socket.io to allow user locate others in a remote location. Now for my next target is I want my application to create some sort of a geofencing that sends notification if users are outside of the boundary.

Now my Question is:

- **Can I do it without using any database?**
- **Is it possible to use only Javascript?**

I'm using Google maps if anyone is asking

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 seems fence/Awareness  API are only for android projects however mine is web-based I probably can't use that

Comment: [You should work on your google-fu](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a way for you to watch for changes in geoposition. [navigator.geolocation.watchPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition)

But there is no geofencing api available, so you have to create that yourself:

I made two classes: `SquareGeofenceRegion` & `CircularGeofenceRegion`
that have the same api's but is calculated differently.

```
class CircularGeofenceRegion {
  constructor(opts) {
    Object.assign(this, opts)
  }

  inside(lat2, lon2) {
    const lat1 = this.latitude
    const lon1 = this.longitude
        const R = 63710; // Earth's radius in m

    return Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) + 
                     Math.cos(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2) *
                     Math.cos(lon2-lon1)) * R < this.radius;
  }
}

class SquareGeofenceRegion {
  constructor(opts) {
    Object.assign(this, opts)
  }

  inside(lat, lon) {
    const x = this.latitude
    const y = this.longitude
    const { axis } = this

    return lat > (x - axis) && 
           lat < (x + axis) &&
           lon > (y - axis) &&
           lon < (y + axis)
  }
}

const fenceA = new CircularGeofenceRegion({
  name: 'myfence',
  latitude: 59.345635,
  longitude: 18.059707,
  radius: 1000 // meters
});

const fenceB = new SquareGeofenceRegion({
  name: 'myfence',
  latitude: 59.345635,
  longitude: 18.059707,
  axis: 1000 // meters in all 4 directions
})

const fences = [fenceA, fenceB]
const options = {}

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(({coords}) => {
  for (const fence of fences) {
    const lat = coords.latitude
    const lon = coords.longitude

    if (fence.inside(lat, lon)) {
      // do some logic
    }
  }
}, console.error, options);
```

I just want to warn you that the watchPosition may not always be trigger while it's in the background: [It is possible to watch the location in the background on Mobile (iOS / Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926217/it-is-possible-to-watch-the-location-in-the-background-on-mobile-ios-android)

Comment: can you explain syntax: `const { axis } = this` ? that  `{ variable } = this` I have not seen it.

Comment: @user305883 This is called "Destructuring Assignement". It was introduced with EcmaScript 2015. It is the same as writing `const varName = this.vaName`.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment